# How to create a zip with a dynamic images gallery in C#?

Tags: c#, github-actions

I have an image gallery where the images are loaded dynamically from a server, and the paths of each image is saved in MySql. Now, I want to have a "Download all images" button, so it generate a `.zip` with all images in the gallery.

The project is hosted on Linux, and to test the updates I use `Github actions`.

To create de `.zip` I found `DotNetZip` Nugget package.

When I do `git push`, on my `Github Actions` I have this error:

> The type or namespace name 'Ionic' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The `ionic` namespace is the namespace that allows me to use `Zipfile`.

I will show you the code...but Visual Studio has no problems.

Html:

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("DownloadAll", "Home", new { pedido = ViewBag.pedido}, FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Descargar Todas las Imagenes" type="submit"/>
            </div>
        }
```

Back:

```
 public FileResult DownloadAll()
        {
            string consulta;
            List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos;

            try
            {
                listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
                consulta = "SELECT DISTINCT p.Pedido, p.Entrega, p.Remito, e.Path, e.Fecha from Pedido p INNER JOIN Entrega e ON p.Entrega = e.Entrega WHERE p.Pedido = " + ViewBag.pedido + " GROUP by e.Path";
                listaPedidos = SelectConexionMySql(consulta);

                using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    foreach (var lista in listaPedidos)
                    {
                        var archivo_nombre = lista.getPathImagen();
                        var archivo_arregloBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(lista.getPathImagen());
                        zip.AddEntry(archivo_nombre, archivo_arregloBytes);
                    }

                    var nombreZip = "ImagenesPedido" + ViewBag.pedido;

                    using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        zip.Save(output);
                        return File(output.ToArray(), "application/zip", nombreZip);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I use MySql query so I can recover the path of the images. Then, I use a `foreach loop` so every path I can save the name and a bytes in the zip.

So, the problem is that `Github Actions` cannot recognize  the `Ionic` namespace, so, how can I create a `.zip` from a dinamic image gallery? I have to add something more so Github can recognize `Ionic`?

Comment: You can use the native [ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-6.0) instead of a 3rd party library.